# Angularjs with Material design md-menu-item multi-column

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

I have created menu as per the demo of the angularjs material. In the demo menu is is dynamic. I have created menu manually. And every thing is working fine.

I just wanted to know that, is it possible to make menu in multi-column rather to make single Drop-down.

Some of my code

```
<md-toolbar>
                    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
                        <md-menu md-position-mode="target-left bottom"  md-offset="-22 6">
                            <md-button aria-label="Plan & Book" ng-click="$mdOpenMenu($event)">
                                Parent Item 1
                            </md-button>
                            <md-menu-content width="4">
                                <md-menu-item>
                                    <md-button>Item 1</md-button>
                                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                                    <md-button>Item 2</md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                <md-menu-item>
                                    <md-button>Item 3</md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
                            </md-menu-content>
                        </md-menu>

                    </div>
                </md-toolbar>
```

My Full codepen http://codepen.io/milindsaraswala/pen/aZJQXO

Let me know please

Comment: Why not use sub-menu instead ?

Comment: As it don't look good and another thing it is website not application

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar

Comment: no it looks more like application. I am looking for website